# Dropwizard admin security

Tags: dropwizard

Is there a way of adding login security to the admin servlet?

Seems like in V0.7 you could add the following two to your yaml file :

```
  adminUsername: user1234
  adminPassword: pass5678
```

However I tried that in the latest version (0.9.2) and it gives me an error saying :
server.yaml has an error:

```
  * Unrecognized field at: server.adminConnectors.[0].adminUsername
    Did you mean?:
      - soLingerTime
      - bindHost
      - idleTimeout
      - useServerHeader
      - useDateHeader
        [14 more]
```

This is what I have :

```
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9180
      adminUsername: user1234
      adminPassword: pass5678
```

Comment: They don't mention in the [configuration reference](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#servers) about this two fields. So probably they don't support them any more.

Comment: Is there another way of adding admin security?

Comment: Probably with some semi-custom code. Check out [their example](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/auth.html#basic-authentication).

Comment: This is for resources you register. The admin resource comes pre-packaged with dropwizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run an app on Heroku which only allows the application to make a single port available.  I attach the `AdminServlet` to the main HTTP port (8080) with this in the `run()` method of my Application (Kotlin):

```
environment.applicationContext.apply {
    setAttribute(MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY, environment.metrics())
    setAttribute(HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY, environment.healthChecks())
    addServlet(NonblockingServletHolder(AdminServlet()), "/admin/*")
}
```

Then, I protect this path with a `BasicAuthFilter` (still Kotlin, you should use it):

```
val basicAuthFilter = BasicAuthFilter("admin", configuration.adminUsername, configuration.adminPassword)
val adminFilter = environment.servlets().addFilter("AdminFilter", basicAuthFilter)
adminFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/admin/*")
```